# Complex Contour Integration 2

Tags: integration

I'm looking to evaluate the a complex integral.

If I let C be the circle $|z|=2$, what is the integral around $C$ of the function $tan(z)$.

I am unclear on how to start this question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: you can write $\tan(z)=\frac{\sin (z)}{\cos(z)}$; $\cos(z)$ has zeroes only in $x=\pi(\frac 12+k)$ for every $k\in \mathbb Z$.

The only two singularities within your contour are $-\frac \pi 2$, $\frac \pi 2$. You can expand $\tan$ in $\frac \pi 2$ as

$$\tan z={\sin z\over\cos z}=-{\cos(z-{\pi\over2})\over\sin(z-{\pi\over2})}={1\over z-{\pi\over2}}\left(- {z-{\pi\over2}\over\sin(z-{\pi\over2})}\cdot\cos(z-{\textstyle{\pi\over2}})\right)\ .$$
and use the regular expansions for $\sin, \cos$.
The expansion in $-\frac \pi 2$ is similar.

From here, just use the residue theorem.